# Compiling Widgets in Qt Creator to use in Qt Designer (plugin dll)

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qt-creator, qt-designer

I've installed 32-bit Qt 5.3 & MS VC 2010 Express on WinXp.   Qt Creator autodetects the compiler and qt installation.

So I opened an existing ("Analog Widgets") .project in Creator , set the Kit to desktop  and hit build.

AFAIK, Qt Designer will show those widgets but it expects a dll in the plugin designer folder.  However, Qt Creator did not generate any .dll, only a .lib.

I tried placing the .lib file in the plugin folder but that didn't work.

How can I build the widget project to generate a dll that Designer will see?

Comment: In your pro file, you have to have `TEMPLATE = lib

Comment: I have TEMPLATE = lib, but it generates a .lib file instead of .dll.